# Refacto multiple cts:element-value-query but a SQL request result

Tags: solr, marklogic

In my marklogic data config file I have a functional entity query who's make the job:

```
<entity processor="MarkLogicEntityProcessor" pk="id"
    preImportDeleteQuery="[...]"
    query="
        declare namespace xms='[...]';
        declare namespace gm='[...]';
        declare namespace qc='[...]';
        declare variable $stop as xs:integer external;
        declare variable $start as xs:integer external;
        let $doc_list := cts:search(collection(),
            cts:and-query((
                    cts:directory-query(('[...]'),'infinity'),
                    cts:or-query((
                        cts:element-value-query(fn:QName('[...]','id'),'id_1'),
                        cts:element-value-query(fn:QName('[...]','id'),'id_2'),
                        cts:element-value-query(fn:QName('[...]','id'),'id_3'),
                        cts:element-value-query(fn:QName('[...]','id'),'id_4'),
                        cts:element-value-query(fn:QName('[...]','id'),'id_5'),
                        [...]
                    )),
                    cts:element-query(fn:QName('[...]','key'),cts:and-query(()))
            ))
        ,'unfiltered')
        [$start to $stop]
        return ($doc_list)"
```

But is there a way to replace the multiple cts:element-value-query lines of the cts:or-query by a custom list of id comes from a SQL request ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function signature of [cts:element-value-query()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-query) allows for more than one value to be passed in. It matches if any value matches - allowing you to also drop the `cts:or-query()` as well,  Something like this shold work if you supply the IDs as a sequence of strings.

```
<entity processor="MarkLogicEntityProcessor" pk="id"
preImportDeleteQuery="[...]"
query="
    declare namespace xms='[...]';
    declare namespace gm='[...]';
    declare namespace qc='[...]';
    declare variable $stop as xs:integer external;
    declare variable $start as xs:integer external;
    let $ids := ("id_1", "id_2", "id_4", "id_4", "id_5", [...]) (: some list supplied from other code:)
    let $doc_list := cts:search(collection(),
        cts:and-query((
                cts:directory-query(('[...]'),'infinity'),
                cts:element-value-query(fn:QName('[...]','id'), $ids),
                cts:element-query(fn:QName('[...]','key'),cts:and-query(()))
        ))
    ,'unfiltered')
    [$start to $stop]
    return ($doc_list)"
```

Comment: Nice one, and how can I get the ("id_1", "id_2", "id_4", "id_4", "id_5", [...]) list from a SQL request ? (I have the fonctional SQL request but I don't succeed to pass the result in the entity query)

Comment: You mean from xdmp:SQL ? You don't explain where your SQL data is.

Comment: I really don't know where to put my SQL request ? maybe from another <entity> ? as
<entity name="my_query" transformer="TemplateTransformer"
  query="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(code SEPARATOR ''',''') as code FROM my_table
  dataSource="my_db"
  rootEntity="true">
 <field column="code" name="code" />
</entity>
and call it as ${my_query.code} ?

Comment: HI. There is alot in your original post and folllowup items. Plus, you tag the post with solr.  The answer above is related to a list of IDS for a single element-value-query.   using the result of "select id from x" via optic or xdmp:sql is then only a map:get() away from a clean list for the above - assuming you are querying MarkLogic. I interpret from above that you are not sure where the data is that you need to query (you make no mention of source of sql data).  It also seems like you are using entity services.  I suggest that you post a question specifically about your last comment.

Comment: Thanks David, I posted in another question